# select top 5 with rank - all results are rank 1

Tags: sql, select, rank

When I perform the below query, all 5 records returned have a rank "1"... but I need to have the record with the highest count be "1", then "2", etc....

I've tried variations of the below query, using different columns in the OVER(), etc... no luck.

```
SELECT TOP(5)
    SearchTerm,
    Category,
    count(''),
    RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY SearchTerm ORDER BY count('') DESC)

FROM 
    Searches

GROUP BY SearchTerm, Category
ORDER BY count('') desc
```

Comment: Try `RANK() OVER(ORDER BY count(*) DESC)` .

Comment: Ding ding ding! thank you!!! I thought the PARTITION BY was required...... turns out the OVER() just needs an ORDER BY.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (the row of SOMERANK can be removed)

```
select ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY SearchTerm) AS MYRANK, *
FROM
(
    SELECT TOP(5)
        SearchTerm,
        Category,
        count('') AS MYCOUNT,
        RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY SearchTerm ORDER BY count('') DESC) AS SOMERANK

    FROM 
        Searches

    GROUP BY SearchTerm, Category
    ORDER BY count('') desc
) T
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution was thanks to @Coder of Code (comment on original post)

Just removing the unnecessary "Partition By" section.

```
SELECT TOP(5)
    SearchTerm,
    Category,
    count(''),
    RANK() OVER(ORDER BY count('') DESC)

FROM 
    Searches

GROUP BY SearchTerm, Category
ORDER BY count('') desc
```